# How to combine Date and Time from 2 different var's in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a User Input which consists of a Date and a Time Input. Both of those values are send as a full date like

```
reminder_date: '2021-02-15T08:00:00.000Z',
reminder_time: '2021-02-09T17:00:00.000Z'
```

But i want to store it in my db as one single value like

```
'2021-02-15T17:00:00.000Z'
```

what is the best approach to achieve that ? split the strings on `T` and then combine or is there a simple way i can take the date part and the time part and create a new `dateTime` to save

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the two items are strings, you could simply use the JavaScript [`substr`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substr.asp) function to get the first 11 characters from `reminder_date` and the second part of `reminder_time` (starting from 11), then concatenate them, *e.g.*

```js
let reminder_date = '2021-02-15T08:00:00.000Z';
let reminder_time = '2021-02-09T17:00:00.000Z';
let reminder_date_time = reminder_date.substr(0, 11) + reminder_time.substr(11);
console.log(reminder_date_time);
```